# Why is Evolution the default mail/calendar package?

Tags: evolution, email, thunderbird, calendar

Why is Evolution the default mail/calendar package that comes with Ubuntu?

Why not Thunderbird + Lightning?

Are there any features in Evolution that are not available in Thunderbird + Lightning?

Can I use the Evolution database via a Samba network share, on a Windows XP or 7 client, just like I can do with Thunderbird?

What happens if I uninstall Evolution from my 10.04 system? Will I lose any integrated functionality built into the system?

Comment: evoltion provides very easy to set up sync of multiple google calanders thunderbird/lightning do not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Evolution indeed is part of the GNOME Project. That's why it's Ubuntu's default mail client, I suppose.

Obviously, this makes it better integrated into the GNOME desktop, especially when running Ubuntu. Please not that some of the following features can be achieved with Thunderbird, too, but it does require some work and doesn't come like that out of the box.

1. **Notifications**: Evolution makes use of native *notify-osd*-notifications whereas thunderbird brings its own notifications and doesn't blend into the desktop as much as Evolution does
2. **Messaging-Menu**: Evolution is integrated into [Ubuntu's Messaging Menue](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MessagingMenu)
3. **GnuPG-Integration**: While Enigmail is good and can be found in the repos, Evolution does come with GnuPG integration without having to install any additional packages

Additionally, some features like Exchange integration are present in Evolution, too. Those, too, could be added to Thunderbird via Extensions. For private desktop use, though, Evolution provides a more integrated experience.

Comment: To be used with the messaging menu the evolution windows has to be open, evolution has to be running! That_s a ridicolous feature. If I have it running I don't really click on the messaging menu to find out whether I have mail!

Comment: BTW: The notes system is also kind of standalone afaik. You can synchronize via Ubuntu One but you cannot replace it with Basket or Tomboy. At least I couldn_t. And try to delete duplicate messages, there's only an outdated plugin, - doesn't work for me.

Comment: @tiax that's a great answer. Thanks. One more question: Can I use the Evolution database via a Samba network share, on a Windows XP or 7 client, just like I can do with Thunderbird?

Comment: @Android Eve: there is no Evolution-for-Windows, so I really doubt you can do that.

Comment: @piedro: that's a known problem with Evolution currently; I think running Evolution in the background needs some complicated changes, which is why it's not implemented (yet).

Comment: @JanC there is an evolution for windows, it's just about 2 versions behind, but it does exist.

Comment: One thing that you forgot though - Thunderbird might be the default email client for GNOME and therefore Ubuntu, it's ugly as heck. Also, the notifications are wacky, but it's integrated with the Messaging Menu in 11.04, at least at this point. It's got it's own menu item (When it's installed)

Comment: Epiphany and F-spot are both GNOME Project applications, however in Ubuntu they are replaced by Firefox and Shotwell respectively.

Comment: @Roland Taylor: I thought Novell never really finished their Evolution-for-Windows port?

Comment: Ah, I found a 3rd-party port by [dipconsultants.com](http://www.dipconsultants.com/evolution/).

Comment: @tiax: you might also want to mention Gvfs-support among the things that Thunderbird doesn't support (how do you attach a document from a user-mounted samba share to a mail in Thunderbird?).

Comment: @piedro: Use alltray to run evolution in the tray. Or just stick it on an un-unused virtual desktop.

Comment: @JanC Last I heard the evolution devs said tray-integration was the responsibility of the desktop, not the application. =/

Answer (score 3):

[Evolution](http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/) like many other applications is part of the [GNOME Project](http://projects.gnome.org/). You're free to replace it at no risk by any email-client you like better.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any features in Evolution that are not available in Thunderbird + Lightning?

Comment: Epiphany and F-spot are both GNOME Project applications, however in Ubuntu they are replaced by Firefox and Shotwell respectively.